# Follow the SOLID principle in Rest Api and Django

Tags: api, django-rest-framework, rest, solid

hi i have two model in *django* like  **Device** and **Data**, the **Data** is related many-to-one to **Device**
and my api returned a list of the Devices and orther api return a list of Data that related to Device.
and the android developer say i have both of that with one request so you must merge tow api to onece
and i try to say it's not best practice and don't followed the SOLID principle .

now what should we do and what approach should we take?

Comment: As per SOLID principle, one is Single Responsibility, each API should have unique functionality. If it is /deviceById as example, it should return multiple data. Similarly a data may also give multiple devices. But two different should not give the same set of data.